# Any analog or parallel approach /result between zero set of algebraic equations system and zero set of Rieman zeta function?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, riemann-zeta

Algebraic geometry may be regarded as research of zero set of algebraic equations system. And there are a lots of approach and result about zero set.

Riemann Hypothesis is about the non-trivial zero set of function $\zeta(x)$

They are all about zero set, but the functions belong to different type.

Any analog or parallel approach /result between zero set by algebraic equations system and zero set of Rieman zeta function?

Comment: No. Did you read any pdf on $\zeta(s)$ and the prime number theorem ? ${}{}{}$.

Comment: @reuns I have the same question about you

Comment: Make some research on MSE you'll see me on almost every question about $\zeta(s)$. Now of course the L-functions and hence the objects [for which](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selberg_class) a (global) RH is conjectured come from some kind of algebraic objects, see [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_zeta_functions) and things like the Langlands program. In other words there is a rich analytic/arithmetic and algebraic theory of L-functions.

Answer (score 3):

Attempting to prove that $\zeta(s) = 0$ forms some sort of generalized variety seems like folly. (Or perhaps brilliant --- but no one has yet gotten anywhere with this thought).

However, there is a connection between algebraic varieties and generalized zeta functions. Namely, suppose $X$ is a smooth closed irreducible variety defined by polynomials $f_1, \ldots, f_d$ over a finite field $F_q$. Let $F_{q^n}$ denote the finite field with $q^n$ elements. Define
$$ N_m = \# \{ u \in X(F_{q^m}) \} = \# \{ u \in F_{q^m}^d : f_i(u) = 0 \;\forall\, i \}.$$
Then we can define a "Hasse-Weil" zeta function
$$ Z(X, t) = \exp \left( \sum_{m \geq 1} \frac{N_m}{m} t^m \right).$$
This function satisfies a functional equation, and it's known to satisfy its analogue of the Riemann Hypothesis. The precise form is sometimes called the Weil Conjectures (proved by Deligne).

Comment: I wonder if there are similar methods or  result, likewise, the zero set form some geometric objects which can be studied by geometricor analytic approach

Comment: @XL_at_China See how the field with one element is [supposed to be](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/69389/riemann-hypothesis-via-absolute-geometry) an attempt to extend the methods for the Weil's conjecture to (zeta-functions of) curves over global fields. Anyway the best is to start with a proof of the [PNT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Proof_sketch).

Comment: @reuns, thank you, I will do.